# Assert onBlur() funciton in functional component jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, ref

I wrote a test case to call `onBlur` method, but I'm getting an error when I try to assert it. Here is the above test case.

```
it("call the handlingBlurEmail method", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <App childRef={() => {}} />
    );
    const comp = wrapper.find({ id: "email" }).first();
    comp.prop("onBlur")({
      target: { id: "email", value: "test@gmail.com" }
    });

    expect(
      wrapper
        .find("AccountForm")
        .state()
        .onBlur()
    ).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

and the function for which I'm writing test case is

```
  mailReference = React.createRef();
  handlingEmailBlur = events => {
    this.mailReference.current.validate(events.target.value);
  };

  render = () {
  ......

    return (
      <div className="Form1">

        onBlur={this.handlingEmailBlur}
      </div>
    )
    .....
    }
```

Please let me know how to add assert statement in order to call the `onBlur()` method in the above test case

Comment: Are you really wanting to test an element's `onBlur` function is called or are you really trying to test that on blur your callback function is correctly called (possibly with specific values)? They aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit testing solution:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  mailReference = React.createRef();
  handlingEmailBlur = (events) => {
    this.mailReference.current.validate(events.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Form1" onBlur={this.handlingEmailBlur}>
        some component
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import App from './index';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

describe('59455504', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('call the handlingBlurEmail method', () => {
    const mailReference = { current: { validate: jest.fn() } };
    jest.spyOn(React, 'createRef').mockReturnValue(mailReference);
    const wrapper = mount(<App childRef={() => {}} />);
    const mEvent = {
      target: { id: 'email', value: 'test@gmail.com' },
    };
    wrapper.find('.Form1').prop('onBlur')(mEvent);
    expect(mailReference.current.validate).toBeCalledWith(mEvent.target.value);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59455504/index.spec.jsx (8.328s)
  59455504
    ✓ call the handlingBlurEmail method (40ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.jsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.769s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59455504

Comment: When I try to follow the above approach, I'm getting the below error    expect(received).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function anonymous]
Not sure if the assertion needs to modified or not.